# How to convert a row in a table into a vector in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

```
t=table(1 2 3 as x, `A`B`C as y, 1.4 1.5 1.6 as z)
```

I need to get the first row and convert it into a vector.

t[0] would give me a dictionary.

t[0].values() returns [1.4,"A",1].

I hope the order of the elements is kept, i.e., I need to get [1,"A",1.4].

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
t[0][t.columnNames()];
```